# Google maps provider, Wifi, 3g and GPS

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps, wifi, 3g

SO, I want to be able to get my location either by gps or by 3g or wifi. For now, I have only managed to find tutorial about gps tracking, so, if anybody knows whre I can find example of provider tutorial for wifi and 3g?

Comment: Everything in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) that refers to `NETWORK_PROVIDER` is covering "3g or wifi".

Comment: i expect that network locations are available even for gsm cell protcols lower than 3g, e.g E (for edge). Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found everything here, you can modify it how you see fit:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java